# Query Overpass API with geocodeArea returns error

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I am trying to send a simple request to `https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter` but I am getting a parser error.

```
{{geocodeArea:Oregon}}->.searchArea;
(
  nwr["waterway"="waterfall"](area.searchArea);
);
out center;
```

> Error: line 1: parse error: Unknown type "{"
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: An empty query is not allowed
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: ';' expected - '{' found.

**Does the API not support the `geocodeArea` option? This exact code works on overpass turbo.**

Comment: geocodeArea is special to the overpass **turbo** api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52236655/how-to-get-a-geocodearea-xxx-query-to-work-in-python-using-overpy

Comment: @Mapperz: there's no such thing as overpass turbo api. It's either overpass turbo (for the web frontend), or Overpass API (for the backend).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{geocodeArea:Oregon}}` is syntactic sugar that was invented by overpass turbo (the web frontend).

Overpass API (the backend) doesn't know anything about those shortcuts.

See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Extended_Overpass_Turbo_Queries for more details.